# If I delete an existing project from Google Cloud API, will it increase my quota?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-api, quota

Suppose I have only 1 project left in my quota. If I delete an existing project, will it make it *2 projects in my quota*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are left with fewer projects in your Quota, a notification will be displayed showing of projects you are left with to do in your Quota Page. If you have reached the Limit, either you can request for Quota increase or you can delete a project.

According to your concern , if you are left with only 1 project in your quota  and if you delete the existing project , it will not immediately make 2 projects in your quota.

Reason is : when we delete or shutdown a project it has a LifeCycle and it stays for 30 days. After 30 days it gets deleted completely.Until it is deleted, the project counts towards your project quota. so basically if you delete your existing project  it will not make 2 projects in your quota until the project  has got deleted completely.

[Managing Project Quota](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#:%7E:text=Once%20you%20have%20reached%20your,request%20a%20project%20limit%20increase.&text=These%20projects%20fully%20delete%20after,Billing%20Quota%20Increase%20support%20page.)

[delete or shutdown a project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_projects)

Comment: So that means after 30 days, if it is completely deleted, I will have 2 projects in my quota instead of 1, isn't it?

Comment: yes after  30 days i.e your project lifecycle, it gets permanently deleted, then you will have 2 projects in your quota.

Comment: If you think this question and its answer shall help other people with similar questions in future, kindly upvote the question.